# Polynomial regression - non-constant residual variance

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity

I have the following regression task.

The dataset below is a list of costs for certain levels of a covariate variable.

```
#       cost covariate
1   280.9079 0.2082548
2   525.5297 0.3221011
3   612.4394 0.3546796
4   685.0576 0.4146610
5   800.6427 0.4707304
6   838.9707 0.5115831
7   881.0105 0.5451114
8   892.4300 0.5539787
9   889.3124 0.5817410
10  933.5286 0.6288167
11  975.0113 0.6789407
12 1012.4021 0.7110753
13 1053.3344 0.7641069
14 1105.4843 0.8266316
15 1125.8921 0.8718025
16 1147.7984 0.9038845
17 1165.1353 0.9329966
```

which plotted is 
[image: cost v covariate]

I'm particularly interested in getting an accurate prediction for values where the value of the covariate is less than 0.80. Also, I need to produce 95% prediction intervals for my estimates.

I've tried to fit a polynomial regression in R using the below:

```
m3 <- lm(cost~poly(covariate,3),data=train)
summary(m3)
```

for which I get

```
Call:
lm(formula = cost ~ poly(covariate, 3), data = train)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-17.592 -13.569   1.341   9.799  18.824 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          877.935      3.202 274.173  < 2e-16 ***
poly(covariate, 3)1  930.340     13.203  70.466  < 2e-16 ***
poly(covariate, 3)2 -232.621     13.203 -17.619 1.87e-10 ***
poly(covariate, 3)3   64.676     13.203   4.899 0.000291 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13.2 on 13 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9976,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.997 
F-statistic:  1767 on 3 and 13 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

When I plot the diagnostics plots using the below:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(m3.0)
```

I notice that the variance of the residuals is not constant.

[image: diagnostics]

how can I best deal with this violation of the model assumptions, given the constraints of my task?

I've tried transforming the variables as well which gained more normality but did very little for heteroskedasticity.

---

**Addition:**

I've noticed that the fit is worse in the central part of the data (between point 1-11) as shown below.

[image: residuals v covariate]

Especially if I look at the residuals as a proportion of the original response variable as below:

[image: Adjusted residuals]

My problem is that the prediction that I need the most are exactly in that area with the worst fit. How can I overcome this? I read one way to achieve this is by using weighted regression, how would I go about it?

Comment: You're explaining nearly 100% of the variance in the outcome. The slight heteroscedasticity will not change your inferences. If you're truly worried, use robust standard errors.

Comment: I see no significant evidence of nonconstant residual variance.  The principal concern should be the effect of the high-leverage point, which is probably the one at the lower left corner.

Comment: @Noah could you expand on why the slight heteroscedasticity will not change the inference since the model explains almost all the variance in the outcome?

Comment: @whuber could you provide your reasoning as to why you don't see any significant evidence of non-constant residual variance? Also, in what way should I be concerned about the high leverage point?

Comment: The high leverage point creates a situation in which your predictions for $x$ near 0.8 depend substantially on a single observed value where $x$ is about as far from there as you can get.  You have to be concerned that your predictions might be skewed simply because you included that point at the bottom left.  You can easily check this: see how the predictions change when you fit the same model with the high-leverage point omitted.

Comment: @whuber thanks, that makes a lot of sense. What about the reasoning of why the variance is not significantly non-constant?

Comment: Two reasons: the first is that it is difficult to distinguish all but the most extreme variation in standard deviations in such a small dataset; the second is the runs of positive and negative residuals suggest some positive serial correlation among the residuals.  Together, these properties indicate that the *appearance* of some changes in the magnitudes of residuals may be just that--an impression, not a reality.  A secondary conclusion is that a cubic polynomial might not be the best choice of a model. As pointed out earlier by @Noah, maybe this doesn't matter.

Comment: @whuber sure I understand. With regards to your second conclusion, if I wanted to try a different model, what would your first alternative option be?

Comment: There's not enough information to decide.  The nature of the response variable and one's expectations about why and how it might vary randomly ought to play important roles in making that determination.

Comment: try plotting cost against log(covariate).

Answer (score 1):

If it might be of some use, my equation search on your data shows an excellent fit to a standard 3-parameter logistic equation, "cost = d + (a - d) / (1.0 + (covariate / c))" with parameters a = -6.5941731503120695E+02, c =  3.4583073606497972E-01, and d =  1.8343212318363612E+03 yielding RMSE = 12.56 and R-squared = 0.9971

[image: plot]

Comment: OPs model yields nearly identical fit with the same number of parameters. This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @alessandro, was the information in this answer of any use or of any value or interest to you?

Comment: @james thanks for your help, I will have a look at how your regression performs against the polynomial. How did you find this model equation?

Comment: Since you ask, my open source online Python curve and surface fitting web site zunzun.com has a "function finder" with hundreds of known, named equations using the scipy differential_evolution genetic algorithm to give initial parameter estimates for the scipy curve_fit() non-linear solver.